# What's the difference between a tachyon and an ordinary bradyon?

Tags: special-relativity, mass, tachyon

I'd like to preemptively apologize for being a bumbling moron, but I can't seem to tell the difference between a [tachyon](http://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tachyon) and a [bradyon](http://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bradyon).

It seems to me that if a tachyon moves symmetrically backward in time and space with symmetrical energy requirements to an ordinary bradyon, there's no reason for me not to believe that the ball sitting on my desk is going through the same motions that I see it going through, just backwards and almost two times the speed of light.  Is there any sort of asymmetry in the system that would make a tachyon going backwards through the space/time continuum on my desk behave differently than the presumably bradyonic ball on my desk?

Answer (score 1):

The Wikipedia article cited below is worth reading,  if you have not done so already.  There are causality related paradoxes and  references to fields with imaginary mass that were originally thought to be the source of tachyons but are now reinterpreted as part of modern particle physics.

[image]

> Because a tachyon would always move faster than light, it would not be possible to see it approaching. After a tachyon has passed nearby, we would be able to see two images of it, appearing and departing in opposite directions. The black line is the shock wave of Cherenkov radiation, shown only in one moment of time. This double image effect is most prominent for an observer located directly in the path of a superluminal object (in this example a sphere, shown in grey). The right hand bluish shape is the image formed by the blue-doppler shifted light arriving at the observer—who is located at the apex of the black Cherenkov lines—from the sphere as it approaches. The left-hand reddish image is formed from red-shifted light that leaves the sphere after it passes the observer. Because the object arrives before the light, the observer sees nothing until the sphere starts to pass the observer, after which the image-as-seen-by-the-observer splits into two—one of the arriving sphere (to the right) and one of the departing sphere (to the left).

Image Source and Text Extract from [Tachyons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tachyon)

The reinterpretation principle asserts that a tachyon sent back in time can always be reinterpreted as a tachyon traveling forward in time, because observers cannot distinguish between the emission and absorption of tachyons. The attempt to detect a tachyon from the future (and violate causality) would actually create the same tachyon and send it forward in time (which is causal).

> Since maybe my understanding of the equations is wrong, let me reexplain so that you can spot my misunderstanding and correct it. A particle that travels below the speed of light is referred to as a bradyon. As the particle approaches the speed of light, time and space begin to shrink down to a single point, until, at the speed of light, the massless particle, the luxon, sees all time and space at the same point. At a speed faster than light, the tachyon would require much energy to stay at its point, and would begin to speed up, as time and space expand into inversions of what they were.

My non expert analysis now follows:)  line 1 and 2, yes. Line 3 depends on the frame of reference. Obviously a photon does not have a point of view, but if an observer was able to almost travel at c,(speed of light), they would not notice anything different about time and space, it would be **everyone else** that had the problems, according to them. I realise you don't mean this literally re the luxon, but as to what a hypothetical observer would observe at c, we have no real  idea, just an extension of theories that predict different effects, depending on who you ask. This is not a cop out, but it's a meaningless question to ask what you would observe at c, as we will never be able to travel that fast.

Your  last line is is a subject  for  debate, because most physicists believe that faster-than-light particles cannot exist because they are not consistent with the known laws of physics. If such particles did exist, they could be used to build a tachyonic antitelephone and send signals faster than light, which (according to special relativity) would lead to violations of causality. How much energy it takes, and if time and space are inverted ( which might happen near a black hole), are subjects that we need to have more, that is, any:), experimental evidence on, otherwise it's metaphysics or philosophy, but it's not physics, so physics can't answer it.

To sum up, physics is based on experiments that can only falsify theories, never completely prove them. Otherwise, without experimentation, it's well founded, plausible speculation at best, (as your question is), and at worst its handwaving, "then some unexplained miracle" happened arguments.
The main argument against tachyons is that causality breaks down, event b causes event a, rather than our usual idea: event a comes first and can only communicate it's consequence to event b at the speed of light. That's why c, the speed of light is important, it ensures causality as we know it.

Finally, if you have ever heard of Feynman diagrams, they do allow us, mathematically only,  to treat a positron (a positively charged electron, which actually do exist) as an electron going backwards in time, but just for the purpose of calculations. The light speed barrier is not a problem here, because positrons and electrons have mass, so they will never reach the speed of light.

Comment: Since maybe my understanding of the equations is wrong, let me reexplain so that you can spot my misunderstanding and correct it.

A particle that travels below the speed of light is referred to as a bradyon.  As the particle approaches the speed of light, time and space begin to shrink down to a single point, until, at the speed of light, the massless particle, the luxon, sees all time and space at the same point.  At a speed faster than light, the tachyon would require much energy to stay at its point, and would begin to speed up, as time and space expand into inversions of what they were.

Comment: I have put our comments in the answer, as it gives me more space to waffle on :)

Comment: I appreciate your answer.  It could be presumed that because tachyons are hypothesized to go against the flow of time, that time MUST be inverted superluminally according to the applicable relativistic equations.  That probably isn't up for debate.  I was hoping that someone who knew more on the relativistic equations could show me whether or not space is predicted to do so as well.  If both are inverted, as I understand it, we may never be able to tell if the plate on my desk is actually experiencing time backwards.  I appreciate your explanation, but it's not what I'm looking for.  upvote

Comment: One area that might be related to what you are looking for are the General Relativity  metric based  equations predicting the behaviour of space and time as an observer/ particle crosses a black hole. They do show an inversion of space and time coordinates, no question about that. The very best of luck with it, and with  getting an answer from a specialist in the field.

Answer (score 0):

I think I may have figured it out.

When time and space invert as a hypothetical space ship exceeds light speed, I'm not sure there's a reason to believe that a speed of 1.999c is not observed to travel at about 1.999c in the direction opposing its velocity.  It might be that according to the equations, as it bypasses c, it simply rebounds in space and time and accelerates (a lot).

Before I accept this as the true prediction according to the equations, I'd appreciate the confirmation of someone who actually knows the equations in the first place, regardless of whether they're experts.